# Exoplayer skip silence

Tags: android, exoplayer

I'd like to add a "skip silence" feature to my audio app which Exoplayer supposedly has:

https://github.com/google/ExoPlayer/issues/4401

However, I can only set the playback speed and pitch and I don't see the skipSilence parameter in the source code:

https://github.com/androidx/media/blob/release/libraries/common/src/main/java/androidx/media3/common/PlaybackParameters.java

I do see there is a SilenceSkippingAudioProcessor class but it's marked as "Unstable":

https://github.com/androidx/media/blob/release/libraries/exoplayer/src/main/java/androidx/media3/exoplayer/audio/SilenceSkippingAudioProcessor.java

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Everything is marked unstable since moving to media3. 
You can set it in the builder:

```
    val exoPlayer = ExoPlayer.Builder(context)
            .setSkipSilenceEnabled(true)
            .build()
```